# How to disable spring sleuth in a certain log level

Tags: spring, cloud, slf4j, spring-cloud-sleuth

I added the sleuth to a microservice and successfully get the Trace Id and span Id, but as you can see after sleuth, missing a part of the info before the log level in the log line.
I think maybe I can disable sleuth in a debug level, to have log line as before and then enable it in the info level.
do you know how or maybe a better solution?

```
before Sleuth:
2022-03-24 09:53:22.338 [(ID:9dcebfa9-b37f-4a94-a91b-45867ea90811)(CUSTOMER ID:*** TYPE:UNKNOWN)] DEBUG 3180716 --- [https-jsse-nio-48082-exec-4] c.h.d.s.staticdata.StaticDataService : start with version: 1.2 OS: ANDROID

after Sleuth:
2022-03-24 10:19:34.541 DEBUG [*****,efcbdb6dc513e468,efcbdb6dc513e468,true] 3368114 --- [https-jsse-nio-48082-exec-7] c.h.d.s.staticdata.StaticDataService : start with version: 1.2 OS: ios
```

Comment: I don't get why having the log level before the squared brackets is a problem